# ROS for Mac OS X , Xcode problem

Tags: macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the Mac OS version of ROS (Electric) on my Macbook, Snow Leopord 10.6. On the page it says requires Xcode 4. Unfortunately apple stopped developing xcode for snow leopard , the last one being 3.2.6. I dont want to upgrade to lion or mountain lion and am quite satisfied with SL. Will ROS work with the present version of xcode 3.2.6 i have on my mac?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42989/ros-for-mac-os-x-,-xcode-problem/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should still work.  As long as Homebrew works on SL still, but I cannot say for sure as I have not installed on SL in a long time.

Good luck, and ask new questions here if you run into trouble.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-09-17**:
i tried to install, but there are many build errors. I guess i will have to switch to ubuntu. One question, I will be using a irobot create with hokuyo lidar and kinect sensor for my PhD soon. Which version of ROS do you suggest would be good for irobot create/roomba. I am looking more into turtlebo

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-09-17**:
I am looking more into turtlebot tutorials and they are using electric and diamondback version. Does ROS versions make any difference on type of robot platform?? Any suggestions, help would be appreciated. Thanks